# Remove unused JavaScript when embed video

Tags: performance, unused-functions

When I tried to embed video from youtube and facebook, it took too much time to load the page. I checked by PageSpeed Insights and it shown third display resource:
[image]
[image]

Do you have any idea that can make unused JS async load, or ignore them so I can have better efficiency? Thanks.